# SIGSEGV on a line without pointers

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, segmentation-fault

It's a Recursive Quick sort, so far it's only failed me with an array of 100000 or bigger (maybe a little smaller). At first I thought it was a memory size problem but it's calling SIGSEGV not stack overflow. I have an iterative version that uses the same partition code and that one works fine. Here's the 
code...

```
template <typename T>
void QuicksortR(T *a, u_int l, u_int r){
    if(r <= l) return;
    u_int i  = Partition(a, l, r);
    if(i-1 < i) //in case of underflow
    QuicksortR(a, l, i - 1);
    QuicksortR(a, i + 1, r);
}

...

template <typename T>
u_int Partition(T a[], u_int l, u_int r){
    u_int i = l-1; //potential underflow fixed by an overflow
    u_int j = r;
    T v = a[r];
    while(1){
        while(a[++i] < v); //overflow fix;
        while(a[--j] > v)
            if(i == j) break;
        if(i >= j) break;
        swap(a[i], a[j]);
    }
    swap(*(a+i), *(a+r));
    return i;
}
```

Comment: If you exceed your allowed stack size, you will get a segfault. And since your question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve], no authoritative answer will be possible.

Comment: There's no question being asked in this question.

Answer (score 0):

> but it's calling SIGSEGV not stack overflow

Nobody is *calling* `SIGSEGV`. `SIGSEGV` is something the kernel *raises* as an exception under certain conditions. One such condition *is* stack overflow, and it's likely happening here.